# hover effect works on two elements, but it should only work on only element

Tags: html, css, hover

I am learning CSS. I get one problem. hover effect should work when the mouse hovers on the box element. when the mouse doesn't hover on the box element, the content element is under box element and should be hidden. now I put mouse under box element (content element), hover effect still works. Why it is like that? and any solution based on my code?

```css
body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            .container {
                width: 1200px;
                height: 300px;
                margin: 240px auto;
                position: relative;
            }

            .container .box {
                position: relative;
                width: calc(400px - 30px);
                height: calc(300px - 30px);
                background-color: #000;
                float: left;
                margin: 15px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-radius: 10px
            }

            .container .box .icon {
                position: absolute;   
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: #f00;
                transition: 0.5s;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .container .box:hover .icon {
                top: 20px;
                left: calc(50% - 40px);
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }          

            .container .box .icon .fas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                font-size: 80px;
                color: #fff;
                transition: 0.5s;
            }

            .container .box:hover .icon .fas {
                font-size: 40px
            }

            .container .box .content {
                position: absolute;
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                top: 100%;
                height: calc(100% - 100px);
                transition: 0.5s;
           
            }

            .container .box:hover .content {
                top: 100px;  
                opacity: 1;  
             
            }

            .container .box .content h3 {
                margin: 0 0 10px;
                padding: 0;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 24px;
            }

            .container .box .content p {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                color: #fff;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">  
       <div class="box">
           <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Search</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
           <div class="icon"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="box">
           <div class="icon"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: because the content element is there.

Comment: any solution for hover doesn't affect on content elemnts

Comment: You've also added a margin on your containers which triggers the hover

Comment: `.container .box .content { display: none; } .container .box:hover .content { display: block }` my guess without running it

Comment: @epascarello animation does work any more

Comment: @j08691 do u have example of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer tools are your friend. Inspect the element and you will see that your `<div class="content">` div is still visible on the page even when you don't hover. Changing the `<p>` color to black will reveal this.

Solution: Add `overflow: hidden` to your `.box` class so the `.content` div will remain hidden unless you hover the `.box` div

```
.container .box {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(400px - 30px);
    height: calc(300px - 30px);
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden; /* ADD THIS */
}
```